# How to access file stored in shared project in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a folder called Documentation inside the shared project, named App2 in this case. How do I access the files stored inside the Documentation folder? Attached image below shows the project structure.

[Visual Studio Solution Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pDrZ.png)

I have tried out following commands but they aren't working :

```
System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory

System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
```

If it's troublesome to access the file in that folder, I'm open to hearing other alternatives.

Comment: that is NOT the startup project.  The startup project would be the iOS or Android project.  To access files in the shared project, it is best to store them as embedded resources.

Comment: @Jason oh I wasn't aware. How do I store them as a embedded resource? Or if I was to store the file in both the iOS and Android project, how do I access them?

Comment: You can store them in the platform projects as Build Type content and just read then using a relative path.  If you want to go the embedded resource route, that is well documented and I don't need to repeat it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I have done it for JSON files in my shared project (using PCL). As Jason pointed out in the comments, if you are using .NET Standard, you can simply define the `GetSharedFile` method in your shared project instead of creating platform specific references.

1. Add the file to the shared project and set it as `Embedded Resource`
2. Create an `IFileHelper` interface in your shared project

```
    public interface IFileHelper {
        Stream GetSharedFile(string fileResourceName);
    }
```

3. Create a new `FileHelper` class in each project (Android and iOS) with the following

```
    public class FileHelper : IFileHelper {
        public Stream GetSharedFile(string fileResourceName) {
            Type type = typeof(IFileHelper); // We could use any type here, just needs to be something in your shared project so we get the correct Assembly below
            return type.Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(fileResourceName);
        }
    }
```

4. Add a documentation handler class in your shared project. Something like below (make sure to change the `App` namespace to match yours):

```
    public class Documentation {
      private const string ResourcePath = "App.Documentation.index.html"; // App would be your application's namespace, you may need to play with the Documentation path part to get it working

      public string GetDocs() {
          IFileHelper helper = DependencyService.Get<IFileHelper>(); // Your platform specific helper will be filled in here

          Stream stream = helper.GetSharedFile(ResourcePath);
          using (stream)
          using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream)) {
              return reader.ReadToEnd(); // This should be the file contents, you could serialize/process it further
          }
      }
    }
```

I wrote this mostly by hand so let me know if something is not working. If you cannot load your file, I suggest trying to put it into the root of your shared project and then changing `ResourcePath` in the code above to the following (again using your app's namespace instead of `App`):

```
private const string ResourcePath = "App.index.html";
```

Comment: you should be able to do this directly in the shared .NET Standard project without having to use DependencyService